# What does the 'global_step' parameter refer to from the 'report_hyperparameter_tuning_metric' function in the hypertune package?

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am using Google Vertex AI to train models, and I am not sure what this parameter is specifying. I noticed that in some Vertex AI tutorials this value was also given a variable value called 'NUM_EPOCHS'. Looking at the [Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-hypertune/blob/master/hypertune/hypertune.py) for the package doesn't add much clarity.

I'm not sure how this can be referring to the number of epochs that the model is trained with, as I feel that can be done more easily just by writing code (and its default value, 1000, seems absurdly high). What does this parameter mean?

Comment: I believe it is related to this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166681/what-does-global-step-mean-in-tensorflow

Comment: Hi @RichMash,  If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Comment: This is a good question. I am not sure if it's related to the other question linked, because that has to do w/ global_step in Tensorflow. This question is for reporting a global step when reporting hyperparameter tuning metrics (of any model/framework) to Vertex AI. My guess is that for its optimization Vertex would like you to report how many steps your local model has made in its training along with the metric name/value you are reporting. Google's documentation could certainly be improved in this regard.

Comment: Hi @Stephen, the global_step in reporting hyperparameter tuning metrics  to Vertex AI refers to the number of batches seen by the graph. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Hi @Stephen, I have added additional details in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

`global_step` in the Training Step is assigned into the `report_hyperparameter_tuning_metric` function which is used to define the number of batches that a graph can see as mentioned in this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166681/what-does-global-step-mean-in-tensorflow). It represents how many batches has the model seen during training, from its start until now.

The function `report_hyperparameter_tuning_metric` is used to record and dump to the file the value of some metric (e.g. loss) in order to understand how well the model is performing. It takes the metric value and the step number (representing how many steps has passed which means how many batches did the model see and records this data point. This function needs to be called after every step (model sees the batch, updates the weights and the metrics values and calls this function), so that the training metrics will be recorded in a 2D plot (number of steps/metric). This step number equals the value of `global_step` which is used to keep track of the number of batches.

The `global_step` is used to keep track of the number of batches seen.It must be an integer variable.Each time a batch is provided, the weights are updated in  a direction that minimizes the loss. When `global_step` is  used with  `optimizer.minimize()`, the variable is increased by one in the global_step argument.